# Shorthand check to map object field value and object key to Tsx element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapping, shorthand

Good evening.

I have an array of objects that I am trying to map to a tsx table element however I need to display the associated key of each field.

I have tried using Object.keys(item)[index] however I can't get it to return a value.
Im looking for help with a short hand check, I have tried a few already but with no success.

```
                  {myArray.map((item: any) => (
                      <TableRow key={item.name}>
                        <TableCell >{item.name === row.name ? `${Object.keys(item)[2]}` && item.a || item.b || item.c || item.d || item.e : null}</TableCell>
                      </TableRow>
                    ))}
```

My array looks like the following:

```
[
  {
   a: 2,
   name: "obj1"
  },
  {
  b: 3,
  name: "obj2"
  },
  {
   c: 2,
   d: 5,
   name: "obj3"
  }
]
```

As I am mapping over the element it will return a table row foreach object, however im trying to get the row data to display as follows.

```
"a 2 ", // this will be the row data for obj1
"b 3 ",
"c 2, d 5"
```

TIA :)

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of the sort of JSX output you're expecting? It's not clear to me what exactly the logic is you're trying to implement

Comment: Hi Sure, I have edited the question, I think it makes more sense but I am not too sure, still quite new to all this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to iterate over the entries (except the `name` key), and join the keys and values together:

```
<TableRow key={item.name}>
  <TableCell>{GetCell(item)}</TableCell>
</TableRow>
```

```
const GetCell = ({ name, ...rest }) => {
  return Object.entries(rest)
    .map(entry => entry.join(' '))
    .join(', ');
};
```

Or if you want a separate cell for each non-`name` key:

```
{myArray.map(({ name, ...rest }) => (
  <TableRow key={name}>{
      Object.entries(rest)
        .map(entry => <TableCell>{entry.join(' ')}</TableCell>)
  }</TableRow>
))}
```

Comment: Hi this is a great answer especially the 3rd solution you provided. However it returns all the fields in all objects in the array per obj
`a 2
 b 3
 c 2 d 5` for each object, so its returns that for obj1, obj2, obj3, it would be correctly if it returned a 2 for obj1 b 3 for obj2. Sorry if I am not communicating correctly. My english is not great.

Comment: Each one of those will be in a separate TableRow though - isn't that what you wanted?  Your question says `"a 2 ", // this will be the row data for obj1
"b 3 "`

Comment: Ah Im so sorry, you are correct. My apologies, sorry to waste your time. The rows are are nested per object. its is a collapsible table. Should I reask the question and mark your answer as correct or edit this one?

Comment: Since the answer works, all you need to do is accept the answer